# What is the proper why to add an outlet to island side panel?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, kitchens, code-compliance

I'm replacing the cabinets on my existing island and preparing it for a waterfall countertop.
I need to move two small appliances outlets to the side where the dishwasher is located.
NOTE: these are for small appliances and not to power the dishwasher.

There is not a lot of space between the panel and the dishwasher so I may need a shallow box in there.

The idea is to keep it safe and comply with NEC.

I considered these two boxes:

1. [1-Gang 17 cu. in. Shallow Old Work PVC Electrical Outlet Box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-1-Gang-17-cu-in-Shallow-Old-Work-PVC-Electrical-Outlet-Box-B117RSWR/202077341)
2. [1-Gang Switch Electrical Box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RACO-1-Gang-Switch-Electrical-Box-410/202056171)

**Question:** I was wondering if there are specific requirement for these boxes (*such as they have to be metal instead of pvc?*) and if the wire can be visible (*secured with staples*) or if I need some sort of conduit to protect it?

*Here is a view of the island and my plan:*

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you will have enough space to use a regular "old work box".

Comment: Is having the wiring and boxes routed using a visible (surface mount) wiring method acceptable, or do the boxes and receptacles need to be concealed?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I guess it has to be visible since it will be in the available space between the dishwasher and the side panel (approx. 2 1/4"). I'm trying to determine what would be acceptable in there.

Comment: @Ebrito -- I meant more that if putting the wiring method and boxes on the *outside* of the island was an option

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I got it now. Now, that is not an option.